# How to get imagemagick to support .flif and .bpg formats?

Tags: imagemagick, image-formats, bpg

For quite some time now there have been several image codecs which provide significant improvements over PNG and JPG, however the latter still remain dominant.

Two formats in particular that I'd really like to see getting more adoption are [FLIF](http://flif.info/) and [BPG](http://bellard.org/bpg/). They seem superior in every possible way to JPG and PNG (except for lacking market acceptance). Especially FLIF seems extremely promising.

TL;DR = Besides supporting them in my own software, is there a way to get FLIF and BPG support in imagemagick?

Comment: When I Google `flif imagemagick`  there seems to be an extension of some sort, and BPG appears to be already supported? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: You might want to use what FLIF transition into, namely, jpeg-xl, (.jxl files), which Imagemagick also supports.

Answer (score 3):

The ChangeLog for ImageMagick says

> 2015-06-25  6.9.1-7 ...  * Support BPG image format

There's no direct BPG support in the ImageMagick source code, but config/delegates.xml lists delegates "bpgdec" and "bpgenc" which convert BPG files to and from PNG files which then get processed by ImageMagick.  You would have to supply those delegates if they aren't already on your system.  You can download the sources for bpgdec and bpgenc from
http://bellard.org/bpg/

There's nothing about FLIF in the ChangeLog, but a "pull request" for FLIF support was recently applied, and coders/flif.c exists in the ImageMagick sources (it requires a separate libflif to work).  You can download the source code for libflif from https://github.com/FLIF-hub/FLIF

I haven't tested either feature.

bpgdec, bpgen, and libflif are all LGPL-licensed, and a reduced version of bpgdec is available under a BSD license.

Answer (score 0):

To get imagicmagick to work with .bpg you have to compile it separate from what is already there.  In other words, you have to add it in.  So download the source code and it doesn't compile.  Give up and use something else or try this because I got it to work

```
use apt-get and install
libpng*
libsdl1*
libsdl2*
libsdl-image*
cmake
libjpeg*
and maybe libjpg*
```

decompress the .bpg files you downloaded and just
use the command
make and sudo make install
AFTER that imagemagick will work with libpg and will not give an error of a missing delegate..